# Remix issue - Uncaught JavaScript exception: abort("NO_DYNAMIC_EXECUTION was set, cannot eval

Tags: solidity, remix

The remix browser was working before.
I was getting "Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.". SO, I added Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * Chrome Extension. 
But the remix stopped working then. Not sure, if this is related.

I have now, removed the extension and cleared the application storage. Still the issue persists.

[image]

Comment: Might be something wrong with remix cause I'm getting the same error. It's about the compiler, I think.

Comment: Yes looks like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the appropriate compiler version and try again.

Example:

If you're using -

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
```

then use the following compiler version -

```
    0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the issue. Now, I am able to proceed with the correct compiler.